# How to solve the "Connection Was Not Closed, The connections current state is open" in c#?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlconnection, sqlclient

So I'm trying to practice c# and stumbled with the connection error, I already stated that my connection will be closed but it tells me that my connection is still open. I really have no idea what's wrong with this.

```
public void getdept()
{
   con.Open();

   string query = "SELECT * FROM positions where PositionName=" + cbxposname.SelectedValue.ToString() + "";

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

   sda.Fill(dt);
       
   foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
   {
       txtdeptname.Text = dr["Department"].ToString();
   }
        
   con.Close();
}
```

Any tips is welcomed!

Comment: There's a lot wrong with that code, even ignoring what I point out in my answer below. Firstly, what possible reason could you have for concatenating an empty string onto the end of that query? It won't hurt but it's like assigning a number to variable and explicitly adding zero. No one would ever do that, so why would you add the empty string?

Comment: Secondly, you should always use parameters to insert values into SQL code. There's less chance of an issue in this case but if you always do the right thing, you'll never get caught out by doing the wrong thing. See [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) for my take on the subject.

Comment: Thirdly, why are you using a `DataTable` and a loop to populate a single `TextBox`? Maybe you have omitted some code for brevity but you should undoubtedly be doing something different. If you're just going to discard the `DataTable` then you should almost certainly be using a data reader instead. If there are multiple rows then you will only see the last one with code like that. If there's only one row, why a loop? If you're only using one column then don't retrieve all columns and if you're only retrieving a single value then you should be calling `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: You might like to check out my ADO.NET examples [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) to learn what to do in different scenarios. That was written some time ago, so certain details could be improved, but the general principles stand about when you use what types of objects and methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unnecessary opening and closing connections in your case. It's not needed here.

Your code should look like this.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
{
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                txtdeptname.Text = dr["Department"].ToString();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

A few suggestions also, Please don't use `*` in the query, instead, use column names, Please use `NOLOCK` in the Query if it's required in your case and use the parameterized query.

Comment: thank you! i deleted the connection statement and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using a common connection object. Don't. Create your connection object where you use. Do so with a `using` statement and then the connection will be closed and destroyed at the end of the block. Store your connection string in a common location and then use that each time to create a new connection, e.g.

```cs
var table = new DataTable();

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SQL query here", connection)
{
    adapter.Fill(table);
}

// use table here.
```

There are a number of things to note from this code, other than the `using` block.

Firstly, it doesn't explicitly open the connection because there's no point. The `Fill` and `Update` methods of a data adapter will implicitly open the connection if it's currently closed and it will implicitly close the connection if it opened it. When using a data adapter, the only reason to open the connection explicitly is if you're calling multiple `Fill` and/or `Update` methods, so the connection is closed and reopened in between. Even if you do open the connection though, there's still no need to close it explicitly because that happens implicitly at the end of the `using` block.

Secondly, this code doesn't create a command object because there's no point. In your original code, you create a command object and then you don't use it. If you already have a command object then you can pass that to the data adapter constructor but you don't do that. You pass the SQL query and the connection, so the data adapter will create its own `SelectCommand`.

In actual fact, there's no point even creating a connection object here. The data adapter has a constructor that accepts a SQL query and a connection string, so you can just create the data adapter and let it do the rest internally:

```cs
var table = new DataTable();

using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SQL query here", connectionString)
{
    adapter.Fill(table);
}

// use table here.
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply! I already solved it by removing the connection statements. And I also cleaned my code as per your suggestion on my post. Thank you very much!